# With a volume-licensed Exchange2010 DVD, can I avoid completely re-installing Exchange2010 Standard Trial?

Tags: exchange-2010, licensing

I have installed Exchange 2010 Standard Trial edition, into our Exchange 2003 environment.  And now, for licensing, I've been provided a completely separate ISO download, volume-licensed for Exchange 2010 Enterprise.  I would really rather enter a product key to my installed Exchange 2010, than have to go through an entire uninstall/reinstall process.

Is there some likely place on the volume-licensed Exchange 2010 DVD -- some specific XML file, perhaps -- where I might locate the slipstreamed product key?  Or is there some option to setup.com that might add the slipstreamed product key to the existing installation?

Comment: What does Microsoft say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to reinstall Microsoft Exchange with the specific DVD...

On your Exchange 2010 server, try opening the Exchange Management Console...

Go to `Server Configuration -> Enter Product Key`.

Try the key. If it accepts, verify the version/edition by right-clicking on the `General` tab when selecting your server.

[**From Microsoft:**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21570)

*For new installations, you may use the software without entering a product key for 120 days after the initial installation only to demonstrate and internally evaluate it. **You may upgrade the trial installation at any time to Exchange Server 2010 SP1 Standard or Enterprise edition by entering a product key.***

After doing so, you'll need to restart the *Microsoft Exchange Information Store* service.

[image]

Comment: I'd love to put the key in like this, but I don't know what it is.  Our Microsoft reseller just provided the VL media, and says the key is embedded in the installer.

Comment: your reseller is wrong.  press them harder.

Comment: I've never seen that. I always have to enter the key. Do you have access to the [Microsoft Volume License Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/Home.aspx)? I believe there's only one setup key. When I buy Exchange Standard, all of my volume licenses use the same setup key...

Comment: I pressed my reseller further, including our campus contact in the conversation.  Our local campus contact was able to provide me a usable product key, noting that it should be kept private and not redistributed.  Thanks, everyone, for your feedback.

Comment: Keep in mind, that key is standard... Exchange 2010  *seems* to use the same keys everywhere...